# Skip Rows with missing values in genfromtxt

Tags: python, csv, file-io, numpy, genfromtxt

how can i load a csv. file into an array skipping rows when at least on cell is empty?
my csv file is large (over 1000 rows and 14 colums):

```
1;4;3
;1;3
;;6
3;4;7
```

i want to skip writing row 2 and 3 cause they have missing values (x;1;3) (x;x;6)
all the other rows that are complete should be written to an array...

These rows (with "full" information in each row should be written to a matrix (array)

```
M = np.genfromtxt(file.csv, delimiter=";",dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 3):

It'll probably be easier to read in all the rows and then keep only the ones without missing data.

```
>>> M = np.genfromtxt("miss.csv", delimiter=";", dtype=float)
>>> M
array([[  1.,   4.,   3.],
       [ nan,   1.,   3.],
       [ nan,  nan,   6.],
       [  3.,   4.,   7.]])
>>> M = M[~np.isnan(M).any(axis=1)]
>>> M
array([[ 1.,  4.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  7.]])
```

(This assumes that you won't have `nan` as a value in `miss.csv` which you want to preserve.  If you do, it'd be a little trickier.)

Comment: i get:  Traceback (most recent call last): File "<console>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: Not implemented for this type – user2956831 just now edit