# python: read complicated csv files

Tags: python, csv, numpy, text

so, I'm trying to read a weird .csv files which has comma separated values, but since each pair of columns represent a different typology of data these are separated by two commas ',,'. On top of that there are missing values in some specific columns after a certain row (see following minimal example)

row1:

> -2.418809,0.004107006,,359.896,1.86897E-07,,359.896,2.958411,,-2.419437,0.1012164,,359.9048,2.095844E-06,,359.9048,-2.049214

row2

> -2.41644,0.004659269,,,,,,,,-2.417068,0.1013545,,,,,,

I've tried to address the problem using the approach described in the answers  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097228/making-np-loadtxt-work-with-multiple-possible-delimiters) but without success because loadtxt can't handle missing values
At the moment I'm trying to read it with numpy.loadtxt specifying only the columns which go on till the end:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(name,
                  delimiter=',',
                  unpack=True,
                  usecols=(0,1,6,7))
```

but I'm obtaining an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

Does anyone have any idea if there is a simple way to solve this?

Comment: `converters` argument in `loadtxt`?

Comment: Foreget the `unpack` parameter.  Use `genfrontxt` to better handle missing data.  I'd also start with `dtype=None`.

Comment: I used the unpack because all the other script I wrote expects the data that way, I didn't want to use genfromtxt at the beginning because I wanted to avoid modifications of the subroutine script  as much as possible. but in the end I just changed the loadtxt with genfromtxt and deleted the nan columns coming out of the double commas (red as comma-missing value-comma from genfromtxt). For the sake of curiosity, what would be the use of dtype=None in thius context?

Answer (score 0):

You have been broken the basic principle of csv
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Complex CSV Solution :

[Handling a complex CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206016/handling-a-complex-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

First step is, if you say the csv uses two commas instead of one, you should pass `delimiter=',,'` to `np.loadtxt`.

Second, if you need to customize the parsing of each column, as Aaron said on his comment, you can pass `converters`to customize the way the data will be stored. Example, if you want that column 2 gives a zero when it finds and empty string, you do

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(name,
              delimiter=',,',
              converters = {2: lambda x: 0 if x == "" else float(x)}
              unpack=True,
              usecols=(0,1,6,7))
```

I didn't test the code, but I checked directly from [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to think how could you do it. If that code doesn't work, it should be something like that anyway.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm assuming you need to do it with numpy. If not, you could just create your own custom function to process it, that should be that hard

Comment: yes i'd like to use numpy and specifically loadtxt to not mess around more than necessary on a bigger script that works nicely, but if I give a ',,' as delimiter then each column will be composed of two of the columns I need, which I guess I could separate in a following step?

Comment: No, forget the last comment, I can use ',' as a delimiter and deal with the two commas as they were delimiting a missing value and get rid of it

Comment: I think that won't work, since the formatting of your floats are like x,xxx,xxx.xx (comma for thousands, and dot for decimals), so you would split one column, into two diferent columns.

Comment: Maybe a different approach could be to open the file before passing it to `loadtxt`, and do a pre-process to replace all ",," with a special character of your choice (e.g: "$"), and then give the processed string to `loadtxt` with delimiter = "$".

Comment: yeah, actually I went for another approach reading everything using genfromtxt (which handles better missing data) and comma as a delimiter, in that way the function considered the ',,' as delimiter-missing data-delimiter returning back essentially all the data with NAN columns where the double-commas were and I just deleted those columns. I might write an answer on that when I'll find the time.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found a non-elegant but working approach: i used genfromtxt which better handles missing data, considering them as NaN by default. Using comma ',' as a delimiter the function reads the double commas ',,' as comma-missing value-comma, so everywhere there is a double comma the output of the function is NaN. that done I just deleted the nan columns applying [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007017/skip-rows-with-missing-values-in-genfromtxt)

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt(namefile,
                     delimiter=',')
datanew = data[:, ~np.all(np.isnan(data), axis=0)]
data = np.transpose(datanew)
```